# Why the java code compile correctly and throw out error while calling the class with passing parameter?

Tags: java, jms

I have been following this url
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JMS5.html
And i have created the connectionfactory, queue and topic. I have been using the source code given on above url to connect the JMS. While i run the following code, there is no any compiling error but the code doesnot run while passing the parameter on it.

```
import javax.jms.*;
import javax.naming.*;

public class SimpleProducer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int NUM_MSGS;

        if ((args.length < 1) || (args.length > 2)) {
            System.out.println("Program takes one or two arguments: " +
                "<dest_name> [<number-of-messages>]");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String destName = new String(args[0]);
        System.out.println("Destination name is " + destName);

        if (args.length == 2) {
            NUM_MSGS = (new Integer(args[1])).intValue();
        } else {
            NUM_MSGS = 1;
        }

        Context jndiContext = null;

        try {
            jndiContext = new InitialContext();
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not create JNDI API context: " + e.toString());
            System.exit(1);
        }

        /*
         * Look up connection factory and destination.  If either
         * does not exist, exit.  If you look up a
         * TopicConnectionFactory or a QueueConnectionFactory,
         * program behavior is the same.
         */
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = null;
        Destination dest = null;

        try {
            connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) jndiContext.lookup("jms/ConnectionFactory");
            dest = (Destination) jndiContext.lookup(destName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("JNDI API lookup failed: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        /*
         * Create connection.
         * Create session from connection; false means session is
         * not transacted.
         * Create producer and text message.
         * Send messages, varying text slightly.
         * Send end-of-messages message.
         * Finally, close connection.
         */
        Connection connection = null;
        MessageProducer producer = null;

        try {
            connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();

            Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            producer = session.createProducer(dest);

            TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();

            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_MSGS; i++) {
                message.setText("This is message " + (i + 1));
                System.out.println("Sending message: " + message.getText());
                producer.send(message);
            }

            /*
             * Send a non-text control message indicating end of
             * messages.
             */
            producer.send(session.createMessage());
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception occurred: " + e.toString());
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                try {
                    connection.close();
                } catch (JMSException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When i run the code using eclipse and passing the parameter for the class i.e paramater myqueue and 3. It returns the following error.

```
Destination name is jms/Queue
JNDI API lookup failed: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
 at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
 at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
 at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
 at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
 at SimpleProducer.main(SimpleProducer.java:53)
```

Do i have to configure any thing in jndi.properties config file in glassfish server. Currently the jndi.properties final has

```
java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory
```

Comment: A successfully compiled code doesn't necessarily will run :)

Comment: Where would you *expect* the compilation error to be? This is valid Java, you just haven't configured your environment correctly for execution time...

Comment: @JonSkeet How can i possibly configured the path. I am currently new to java and JMS.

Comment: I don't know, not having used JMS myself. I suggest you read a good JMS/JNDI tutorial. But I'm surprised that *you're* surprised that something can compile but still fail at execution time. That was my point - you seem to have expected a compilation failure... where do you think it should have occurred?

Answer (score 0):

The URL you provided has a section "Creating JMS Administered Objects". You should follow those steps to properly configure your testing environment.

The tutorial teaches you how to configure that using a web interface, but you should be able to find the config files on the server to apply the same data to your Eclipse environment later.

Glassfish has a similar web console. You should be able to create Connection Factory in a similar way as the tutorial teaches.